# toString не "читается"

Tags: javascript

```
function createPhoneNumber(numbers){
    var one = one.toString(numbers[0]); 
    var two = two.toString(numbers[1]); 
    var three = three.toString(numbers[2]); 
    var four = four.toString(numbers[3]) ;
    var five = five.toString(numbers[4]); 
    var six = six.toString(numbers[5]) ;
    var seven = seven.toString(numbers[6]) ;
    var eight = eight.toString(numbers[7]) ;
    var nine = nine.toString(numbers[8]) ;
    var ten = ten.toString(numbers[9]);
    var f = "(" + one + two + three + ")";
    return f + '' + four + five + six + "-" + seven + eight + nine + ten;
  } 
  alert(createPhoneNumber(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0))
```

Здесь просто надо вывести номер телефона.

Answer (score 0):

`var one = one.toString(numbers[0]);` — При запуске фукнции, сперва создаются все переменные, объявленные через `var` (получая значение undefined) независимо от их места в коде. Потом код выполняется сверху вниз, должно сработать присваивание `= one.toString(numbers[0])` — в этот момент `one` уже существует (undefined), получается ошибка `Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`

Что-то близкое вашей функции можно получить так:

```js
console.log(createPhoneNumber(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0))

function createPhoneNumber(...numbers) {
  // Если без многоточия - надо через запятую в скобках указать 10 переменных.
  var one = numbers[0].toString();
  var two = numbers[1].toString();
  var three = numbers[2].toString();
  var four = numbers[3].toString();
  var five = numbers[4].toString();
  var six = numbers[5].toString();
  var seven = numbers[6].toString();
  var eight = numbers[7].toString();
  var nine = numbers[8].toString();
  var ten = numbers[9].toString();
  var f = "(" + one + two + three + ")";
  
  return f + '' + four + five + six + "-" + seven + eight + nine + ten;
}
```

Можно еще все аргументы завернуть в массив и приклеить элементы через join. Они и так превратятся в строку. А скобки и черточку вставить через [Регулярные выражения](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html):

```js
console.log( createPhoneNumber(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0) );

function createPhoneNumber(){
  return [...arguments].join("").replace(/(\d{3})/, "($1)").replace(/\)(\d{3})/, ")$1-");
}
```

А еще лучше изначально передавать в функцию массив чисел, а не 10 аргументов.