# Сумма минимальных значений в многомерном массиве

Tags: javascript

```
function sumOfMinimums(arr) {
  var i = 0
  for(i = 0 ; i <= arr.lenght; i ++){
    arr[i].sort();
    var sum =0;
    sum+= arr[i][0]
  }
  return sum
}
```

Я так понимаю, у меня проблема в нахождении элемента в многомерном массиве

Comment: попробуйте var sum = 0 поставить перед циклом, похоже, что у вас считает только последний минимальный элемент

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1089427/tostring-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f

Comment: Вместо дорогой сортировки найдите минимальное число в массиве с помощью простого перебора массива.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

У Вас несколько проблем:

1. Опечатка в названии свойства `length`.
2. Обнуление переменной `sum` на каждой итерации цикла.
3. Сортировка массива с использованием сравнивателя по умолчанию, который сравнивает элементы массива как строки.

Answer (score 3):

```js
let Arr = [[9,3,8,5,1],[2,7,1,2.6],[7,3,11,7,8]];
function sumOfMinimums(arr) {
    var sum =0;
    for(let i = 0 ;i<arr.length; i++){
        arr[i].sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
        sum += +arr[i][0]
    }
    return sum
}
console.log(sumOfMinimums(Arr));
```

Comment: Замените одну из единиц на 11.

Comment: @Igor Спасибо за замечание, добавил.

Answer (score 0):

Забудьте пжл про var в 2020.

```
let sortArr = (arr) => {
let sum;
   for(let el of arr) {
     el.sort((a, b) => a - b);
     sum += +el[0];
    };
return sum;
  };
```

Comment: Да знаю я знаю)) Только мне надо просуммировать минимальные значения

Comment: Я затестил, но все равно что-то не работает

Comment: Поправил, добавив сумму мин значений)